# Sort TimeZone based on GMT time in a list of timezone String

Tags: java, sorting, timezone

I am trying to display timezone in user preference page based on GMT time. 
Where i am stuck is i am trying to sort this timezone based on GMT time instated of alphabet order. like

```
(GMT+3:00) Indian/Mayotte (GMT+3:00) W-SU (GMT+3:30) Asia/Tehran
(GMT+3:30) Iran (GMT+4:00) Asia/Baku (GMT+4:00) Asia/Dubai
(GMT+4:00) Asia/Muscat (GMT+4:00) Asia/Tbilisi (GMT+4:00)
Asia/Yerevan (GMT+4:00) Etc/GMT-4 (GMT+4:00) Europe/Samara
(GMT+4:00) Indian/Mahe (GMT+4:00) Indian/Mauritius (GMT+4:00)
Indian/Reunion (GMT+4:00) NET (GMT+4:30) Asia/Kabul (GMT+5:00)
Antarctica/Mawson (GMT+5:00) Asia/Aqtau
```

What i am now getting using comparator is which is not still properly ordered based on time in string:

[image]

I need to sort based on alpha numeric and - + operator like -10,-9,-1,0,1,2,3... can anyone help in this.

```
public class ComboDropDownItem {
    private String key;
    private String value;

    public ComboDropDownItem(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
  }  

public class Timezoner {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<ComboDropDownItem> comboDropDownItem = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] ids = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
    for (String id : ids) {
        comboDropDownItem.add(
    new ComboDropDownItem(TimeZone.getTimeZone(id).getID(),            
     getTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(id))));
    }
     Collections.sort(comboDropDownItem, 
             new Comparator<ComboDropDownItem>() {
        public int compare(ComboDropDownItem s1, ComboDropDownItem s2) {
            return s1.getValue().compareToIgnoreCase(s2.getValue());
        }
    }); // Need to sort the GMT timezone here after getTimeZone() method call
    for (ComboDropDownItem instance : comboDropDownItem) {
         System.out.println(instance.getValue());

    }
  }

   private static String getTimeZone(TimeZone tz) {
    long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(tz.getRawOffset());
    long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(tz.getRawOffset()) 
             - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(hours);
    minutes = Math.abs(minutes);
    String result = "";
    if (hours > 0) {
    result = String.format("(GMT+%d:%02d) %s", hours, minutes, tz.getID());
    } else if (hours < 0) {
    result = String.format("(GMT%d:%02d) %s", hours, minutes, tz.getID());
    } else {
        result = String.format("(GMT) %s", tz.getID());
    }
    return result;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sort the `TimeZone` values first, using their `rawOffset`, for example...

```
    List<TimeZone> comboDropDownItem = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] ids = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
    for (String id : ids) {
        comboDropDownItem.add(TimeZone.getTimeZone(id));
    }
    Collections.sort(comboDropDownItem,
                    new Comparator<TimeZone>() {
        public int compare(TimeZone s1, TimeZone s2) {
            return s1.getRawOffset() - s2.getRawOffset();
        }
    }); // Need to sort the GMT timezone here after getTimeZone() method call
    for (TimeZone instance : comboDropDownItem) {
        System.out.println(getTimeZone(instance) + instance.getID());

    }
```

Then using the sorted `List`, generate your combobox

If you're wondering, the above code will print

```
(GMT-12:00) Etc/GMT+12Etc/GMT+12
(GMT-11:00) Etc/GMT+11Etc/GMT+11
(GMT-11:00) Pacific/MidwayPacific/Midway
(GMT-11:00) Pacific/NiuePacific/Niue
(GMT-11:00) Pacific/Pago_PagoPacific/Pago_Pago
(GMT-11:00) Pacific/SamoaPacific/Samoa
(GMT-11:00) US/SamoaUS/Samoa
(GMT-10:00) America/AdakAmerica/Adak
(GMT-10:00) America/AtkaAmerica/Atka
(GMT-10:00) Etc/GMT+10Etc/GMT+10
(GMT-10:00) Pacific/HonoluluPacific/Honolulu
(GMT-10:00) Pacific/JohnstonPacific/Johnston
(GMT-10:00) Pacific/RarotongaPacific/Rarotonga
(GMT-10:00) Pacific/TahitiPacific/Tahiti
(GMT-10:00) SystemV/HST10SystemV/HST10
(GMT-10:00) US/AleutianUS/Aleutian
(GMT-10:00) US/HawaiiUS/Hawaii
(GMT-10:00) HSTHST
(GMT-9:30) Pacific/MarquesasPacific/Marquesas
(GMT-9:00) America/AnchorageAmerica/Anchorage
(GMT-9:00) America/JuneauAmerica/Juneau
(GMT-9:00) America/NomeAmerica/Nome
(GMT-9:00) America/SitkaAmerica/Sitka
(GMT-9:00) America/YakutatAmerica/Yakutat
(GMT-9:00) Etc/GMT+9Etc/GMT+9
(GMT-9:00) Pacific/GambierPacific/Gambier
(GMT-9:00) SystemV/YST9SystemV/YST9
(GMT-9:00) SystemV/YST9YDTSystemV/YST9YDT
(GMT-9:00) US/AlaskaUS/Alaska
(GMT-9:00) ASTAST
(GMT-8:00) America/DawsonAmerica/Dawson
(GMT-8:00) America/EnsenadaAmerica/Ensenada
(GMT-8:00) America/Los_AngelesAmerica/Los_Angeles
(GMT-8:00) America/MetlakatlaAmerica/Metlakatla
(GMT-8:00) America/Santa_IsabelAmerica/Santa_Isabel
(GMT-8:00) America/TijuanaAmerica/Tijuana
(GMT-8:00) America/VancouverAmerica/Vancouver
(GMT-8:00) America/WhitehorseAmerica/Whitehorse
(GMT-8:00) Canada/PacificCanada/Pacific
(GMT-8:00) Canada/YukonCanada/Yukon
(GMT-8:00) Etc/GMT+8Etc/GMT+8
(GMT-8:00) Mexico/BajaNorteMexico/BajaNorte
(GMT-8:00) PST8PDTPST8PDT
(GMT-8:00) Pacific/PitcairnPacific/Pitcairn
(GMT-8:00) SystemV/PST8SystemV/PST8
(GMT-8:00) SystemV/PST8PDTSystemV/PST8PDT
(GMT-8:00) US/PacificUS/Pacific
(GMT-8:00) US/Pacific-NewUS/Pacific-New
(GMT-8:00) PSTPST
(GMT-7:00) America/BoiseAmerica/Boise
(GMT-7:00) America/Cambridge_BayAmerica/Cambridge_Bay
(GMT-7:00) America/ChihuahuaAmerica/Chihuahua
(GMT-7:00) America/CrestonAmerica/Creston
(GMT-7:00) America/Dawson_CreekAmerica/Dawson_Creek
(GMT-7:00) America/DenverAmerica/Denver
(GMT-7:00) America/EdmontonAmerica/Edmonton
(GMT-7:00) America/HermosilloAmerica/Hermosillo
(GMT-7:00) America/InuvikAmerica/Inuvik
(GMT-7:00) America/MazatlanAmerica/Mazatlan
(GMT-7:00) America/OjinagaAmerica/Ojinaga
(GMT-7:00) America/PhoenixAmerica/Phoenix
(GMT-7:00) America/ShiprockAmerica/Shiprock
(GMT-7:00) America/YellowknifeAmerica/Yellowknife
(GMT-7:00) Canada/MountainCanada/Mountain
(GMT-7:00) Etc/GMT+7Etc/GMT+7
(GMT-7:00) MST7MDTMST7MDT
(GMT-7:00) Mexico/BajaSurMexico/BajaSur
(GMT-7:00) NavajoNavajo
(GMT-7:00) SystemV/MST7SystemV/MST7
(GMT-7:00) SystemV/MST7MDTSystemV/MST7MDT
(GMT-7:00) US/ArizonaUS/Arizona
(GMT-7:00) US/MountainUS/Mountain
(GMT-7:00) MSTMST
(GMT-7:00) PNTPNT
(GMT-6:00) America/Bahia_BanderasAmerica/Bahia_Banderas
(GMT-6:00) America/BelizeAmerica/Belize
(GMT-6:00) America/CancunAmerica/Cancun
(GMT-6:00) America/ChicagoAmerica/Chicago
(GMT-6:00) America/Costa_RicaAmerica/Costa_Rica
(GMT-6:00) America/El_SalvadorAmerica/El_Salvador
(GMT-6:00) America/GuatemalaAmerica/Guatemala
(GMT-6:00) America/Indiana/KnoxAmerica/Indiana/Knox
(GMT-6:00) America/Indiana/Tell_CityAmerica/Indiana/Tell_City
(GMT-6:00) America/Knox_INAmerica/Knox_IN
(GMT-6:00) America/ManaguaAmerica/Managua
(GMT-6:00) America/MatamorosAmerica/Matamoros
(GMT-6:00) America/MenomineeAmerica/Menominee
(GMT-6:00) America/MeridaAmerica/Merida
(GMT-6:00) America/Mexico_CityAmerica/Mexico_City
(GMT-6:00) America/MonterreyAmerica/Monterrey
(GMT-6:00) America/North_Dakota/BeulahAmerica/North_Dakota/Beulah
(GMT-6:00) America/North_Dakota/CenterAmerica/North_Dakota/Center
(GMT-6:00) America/North_Dakota/New_SalemAmerica/North_Dakota/New_Salem
(GMT-6:00) America/Rainy_RiverAmerica/Rainy_River
(GMT-6:00) America/Rankin_InletAmerica/Rankin_Inlet
(GMT-6:00) America/ReginaAmerica/Regina
(GMT-6:00) America/ResoluteAmerica/Resolute
(GMT-6:00) America/Swift_CurrentAmerica/Swift_Current
(GMT-6:00) America/TegucigalpaAmerica/Tegucigalpa
(GMT-6:00) America/WinnipegAmerica/Winnipeg
(GMT-6:00) CST6CDTCST6CDT
(GMT-6:00) Canada/CentralCanada/Central
(GMT-6:00) Canada/East-SaskatchewanCanada/East-Saskatchewan
(GMT-6:00) Canada/SaskatchewanCanada/Saskatchewan
(GMT-6:00) Chile/EasterIslandChile/EasterIsland
(GMT-6:00) Etc/GMT+6Etc/GMT+6
(GMT-6:00) Mexico/GeneralMexico/General
(GMT-6:00) Pacific/EasterPacific/Easter
(GMT-6:00) Pacific/GalapagosPacific/Galapagos
(GMT-6:00) SystemV/CST6SystemV/CST6
(GMT-6:00) SystemV/CST6CDTSystemV/CST6CDT
(GMT-6:00) US/CentralUS/Central
(GMT-6:00) US/Indiana-StarkeUS/Indiana-Starke
(GMT-6:00) CSTCST
(GMT-5:00) America/AtikokanAmerica/Atikokan
(GMT-5:00) America/BogotaAmerica/Bogota
(GMT-5:00) America/CaymanAmerica/Cayman
(GMT-5:00) America/Coral_HarbourAmerica/Coral_Harbour
(GMT-5:00) America/DetroitAmerica/Detroit
(GMT-5:00) America/EirunepeAmerica/Eirunepe
(GMT-5:00) America/Fort_WayneAmerica/Fort_Wayne
(GMT-5:00) America/Grand_TurkAmerica/Grand_Turk
(GMT-5:00) America/GuayaquilAmerica/Guayaquil
(GMT-5:00) America/HavanaAmerica/Havana
(GMT-5:00) America/Indiana/IndianapolisAmerica/Indiana/Indianapolis
(GMT-5:00) America/Indiana/MarengoAmerica/Indiana/Marengo
(GMT-5:00) America/Indiana/PetersburgAmerica/Indiana/Petersburg
(GMT-5:00) America/Indiana/VevayAmerica/Indiana/Vevay
(GMT-5:00) America/Indiana/VincennesAmerica/Indiana/Vincennes
(GMT-5:00) America/Indiana/WinamacAmerica/Indiana/Winamac
(GMT-5:00) America/IndianapolisAmerica/Indianapolis
(GMT-5:00) America/IqaluitAmerica/Iqaluit
(GMT-5:00) America/JamaicaAmerica/Jamaica
(GMT-5:00) America/Kentucky/LouisvilleAmerica/Kentucky/Louisville
(GMT-5:00) America/Kentucky/MonticelloAmerica/Kentucky/Monticello
(GMT-5:00) America/LimaAmerica/Lima
(GMT-5:00) America/LouisvilleAmerica/Louisville
(GMT-5:00) America/MontrealAmerica/Montreal
(GMT-5:00) America/NassauAmerica/Nassau
(GMT-5:00) America/New_YorkAmerica/New_York
(GMT-5:00) America/NipigonAmerica/Nipigon
(GMT-5:00) America/PanamaAmerica/Panama
(GMT-5:00) America/PangnirtungAmerica/Pangnirtung
(GMT-5:00) America/Port-au-PrinceAmerica/Port-au-Prince
(GMT-5:00) America/Porto_AcreAmerica/Porto_Acre
(GMT-5:00) America/Rio_BrancoAmerica/Rio_Branco
(GMT-5:00) America/Thunder_BayAmerica/Thunder_Bay
(GMT-5:00) America/TorontoAmerica/Toronto
(GMT-5:00) Brazil/AcreBrazil/Acre
(GMT-5:00) Canada/EasternCanada/Eastern
(GMT-5:00) CubaCuba
(GMT-5:00) EST5EDTEST5EDT
(GMT-5:00) Etc/GMT+5Etc/GMT+5
(GMT-5:00) JamaicaJamaica
(GMT-5:00) SystemV/EST5SystemV/EST5
(GMT-5:00) SystemV/EST5EDTSystemV/EST5EDT
(GMT-5:00) US/East-IndianaUS/East-Indiana
(GMT-5:00) US/EasternUS/Eastern
(GMT-5:00) US/MichiganUS/Michigan
(GMT-5:00) ESTEST
(GMT-5:00) IETIET
(GMT-4:30) America/CaracasAmerica/Caracas
(GMT-4:00) America/AnguillaAmerica/Anguilla
(GMT-4:00) America/AntiguaAmerica/Antigua
(GMT-4:00) America/ArubaAmerica/Aruba
(GMT-4:00) America/AsuncionAmerica/Asuncion
(GMT-4:00) America/BarbadosAmerica/Barbados
(GMT-4:00) America/Blanc-SablonAmerica/Blanc-Sablon
(GMT-4:00) America/Boa_VistaAmerica/Boa_Vista
(GMT-4:00) America/Campo_GrandeAmerica/Campo_Grande
(GMT-4:00) America/CuiabaAmerica/Cuiaba
(GMT-4:00) America/CuracaoAmerica/Curacao
(GMT-4:00) America/DominicaAmerica/Dominica
(GMT-4:00) America/Glace_BayAmerica/Glace_Bay
(GMT-4:00) America/Goose_BayAmerica/Goose_Bay
(GMT-4:00) America/GrenadaAmerica/Grenada
(GMT-4:00) America/GuadeloupeAmerica/Guadeloupe
(GMT-4:00) America/GuyanaAmerica/Guyana
(GMT-4:00) America/HalifaxAmerica/Halifax
(GMT-4:00) America/KralendijkAmerica/Kralendijk
(GMT-4:00) America/La_PazAmerica/La_Paz
(GMT-4:00) America/Lower_PrincesAmerica/Lower_Princes
(GMT-4:00) America/ManausAmerica/Manaus
(GMT-4:00) America/MarigotAmerica/Marigot
(GMT-4:00) America/MartiniqueAmerica/Martinique
(GMT-4:00) America/MonctonAmerica/Moncton
(GMT-4:00) America/MontserratAmerica/Montserrat
(GMT-4:00) America/Port_of_SpainAmerica/Port_of_Spain
(GMT-4:00) America/Porto_VelhoAmerica/Porto_Velho
(GMT-4:00) America/Puerto_RicoAmerica/Puerto_Rico
(GMT-4:00) America/SantiagoAmerica/Santiago
(GMT-4:00) America/Santo_DomingoAmerica/Santo_Domingo
(GMT-4:00) America/St_BarthelemyAmerica/St_Barthelemy
(GMT-4:00) America/St_KittsAmerica/St_Kitts
(GMT-4:00) America/St_LuciaAmerica/St_Lucia
(GMT-4:00) America/St_ThomasAmerica/St_Thomas
(GMT-4:00) America/St_VincentAmerica/St_Vincent
(GMT-4:00) America/ThuleAmerica/Thule
(GMT-4:00) America/TortolaAmerica/Tortola
(GMT-4:00) America/VirginAmerica/Virgin
(GMT-4:00) Antarctica/PalmerAntarctica/Palmer
(GMT-4:00) Atlantic/BermudaAtlantic/Bermuda
(GMT-4:00) Brazil/WestBrazil/West
(GMT-4:00) Canada/AtlanticCanada/Atlantic
(GMT-4:00) Chile/ContinentalChile/Continental
(GMT-4:00) Etc/GMT+4Etc/GMT+4
(GMT-4:00) SystemV/AST4SystemV/AST4
(GMT-4:00) SystemV/AST4ADTSystemV/AST4ADT
(GMT-4:00) PRTPRT
(GMT-3:30) America/St_JohnsAmerica/St_Johns
(GMT-3:30) Canada/NewfoundlandCanada/Newfoundland
(GMT-3:30) CNTCNT
(GMT-3:00) America/AraguainaAmerica/Araguaina
(GMT-3:00) America/Argentina/Buenos_AiresAmerica/Argentina/Buenos_Aires
(GMT-3:00) America/Argentina/CatamarcaAmerica/Argentina/Catamarca
(GMT-3:00) America/Argentina/ComodRivadaviaAmerica/Argentina/ComodRivadavia
(GMT-3:00) America/Argentina/CordobaAmerica/Argentina/Cordoba
(GMT-3:00) America/Argentina/JujuyAmerica/Argentina/Jujuy
(GMT-3:00) America/Argentina/La_RiojaAmerica/Argentina/La_Rioja
(GMT-3:00) America/Argentina/MendozaAmerica/Argentina/Mendoza
(GMT-3:00) America/Argentina/Rio_GallegosAmerica/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos
(GMT-3:00) America/Argentina/SaltaAmerica/Argentina/Salta
(GMT-3:00) America/Argentina/San_JuanAmerica/Argentina/San_Juan
(GMT-3:00) America/Argentina/San_LuisAmerica/Argentina/San_Luis
(GMT-3:00) America/Argentina/TucumanAmerica/Argentina/Tucuman
(GMT-3:00) America/Argentina/UshuaiaAmerica/Argentina/Ushuaia
(GMT-3:00) America/BahiaAmerica/Bahia
(GMT-3:00) America/BelemAmerica/Belem
(GMT-3:00) America/Buenos_AiresAmerica/Buenos_Aires
(GMT-3:00) America/CatamarcaAmerica/Catamarca
(GMT-3:00) America/CayenneAmerica/Cayenne
(GMT-3:00) America/CordobaAmerica/Cordoba
(GMT-3:00) America/FortalezaAmerica/Fortaleza
(GMT-3:00) America/GodthabAmerica/Godthab
(GMT-3:00) America/JujuyAmerica/Jujuy
(GMT-3:00) America/MaceioAmerica/Maceio
(GMT-3:00) America/MendozaAmerica/Mendoza
(GMT-3:00) America/MiquelonAmerica/Miquelon
(GMT-3:00) America/MontevideoAmerica/Montevideo
(GMT-3:00) America/ParamariboAmerica/Paramaribo
(GMT-3:00) America/RecifeAmerica/Recife
(GMT-3:00) America/RosarioAmerica/Rosario
(GMT-3:00) America/SantaremAmerica/Santarem
(GMT-3:00) America/Sao_PauloAmerica/Sao_Paulo
(GMT-3:00) Antarctica/RotheraAntarctica/Rothera
(GMT-3:00) Atlantic/StanleyAtlantic/Stanley
(GMT-3:00) Brazil/EastBrazil/East
(GMT-3:00) Etc/GMT+3Etc/GMT+3
(GMT-3:00) AGTAGT
(GMT-3:00) BETBET
(GMT-2:00) America/NoronhaAmerica/Noronha
(GMT-2:00) Atlantic/South_GeorgiaAtlantic/South_Georgia
(GMT-2:00) Brazil/DeNoronhaBrazil/DeNoronha
(GMT-2:00) Etc/GMT+2Etc/GMT+2
(GMT-1:00) America/ScoresbysundAmerica/Scoresbysund
(GMT-1:00) Atlantic/AzoresAtlantic/Azores
(GMT-1:00) Atlantic/Cape_VerdeAtlantic/Cape_Verde
(GMT-1:00) Etc/GMT+1Etc/GMT+1
(GMT) Africa/AbidjanAfrica/Abidjan
(GMT) Africa/AccraAfrica/Accra
(GMT) Africa/BamakoAfrica/Bamako
(GMT) Africa/BanjulAfrica/Banjul
(GMT) Africa/BissauAfrica/Bissau
(GMT) Africa/CasablancaAfrica/Casablanca
(GMT) Africa/ConakryAfrica/Conakry
(GMT) Africa/DakarAfrica/Dakar
(GMT) Africa/El_AaiunAfrica/El_Aaiun
(GMT) Africa/FreetownAfrica/Freetown
(GMT) Africa/LomeAfrica/Lome
(GMT) Africa/MonroviaAfrica/Monrovia
(GMT) Africa/NouakchottAfrica/Nouakchott
(GMT) Africa/OuagadougouAfrica/Ouagadougou
(GMT) Africa/Sao_TomeAfrica/Sao_Tome
(GMT) Africa/TimbuktuAfrica/Timbuktu
(GMT) America/DanmarkshavnAmerica/Danmarkshavn
(GMT) Atlantic/CanaryAtlantic/Canary
(GMT) Atlantic/FaeroeAtlantic/Faeroe
(GMT) Atlantic/FaroeAtlantic/Faroe
(GMT) Atlantic/MadeiraAtlantic/Madeira
(GMT) Atlantic/ReykjavikAtlantic/Reykjavik
(GMT) Atlantic/St_HelenaAtlantic/St_Helena
(GMT) EireEire
(GMT) Etc/GMTEtc/GMT
(GMT) Etc/GMT+0Etc/GMT+0
(GMT) Etc/GMT-0Etc/GMT-0
(GMT) Etc/GMT0Etc/GMT0
(GMT) Etc/GreenwichEtc/Greenwich
(GMT) Etc/UCTEtc/UCT
(GMT) Etc/UTCEtc/UTC
(GMT) Etc/UniversalEtc/Universal
(GMT) Etc/ZuluEtc/Zulu
(GMT) Europe/BelfastEurope/Belfast
(GMT) Europe/DublinEurope/Dublin
(GMT) Europe/GuernseyEurope/Guernsey
(GMT) Europe/Isle_of_ManEurope/Isle_of_Man
(GMT) Europe/JerseyEurope/Jersey
(GMT) Europe/LisbonEurope/Lisbon
(GMT) Europe/LondonEurope/London
(GMT) GBGB
(GMT) GB-EireGB-Eire
(GMT) GMTGMT
(GMT) GMT0GMT0
(GMT) GreenwichGreenwich
(GMT) IcelandIceland
(GMT) PortugalPortugal
(GMT) UCTUCT
(GMT) UTCUTC
(GMT) UniversalUniversal
(GMT) WETWET
(GMT) ZuluZulu
(GMT+1:00) Africa/AlgiersAfrica/Algiers
(GMT+1:00) Africa/BanguiAfrica/Bangui
(GMT+1:00) Africa/BrazzavilleAfrica/Brazzaville
(GMT+1:00) Africa/CeutaAfrica/Ceuta
(GMT+1:00) Africa/DoualaAfrica/Douala
(GMT+1:00) Africa/KinshasaAfrica/Kinshasa
(GMT+1:00) Africa/LagosAfrica/Lagos
(GMT+1:00) Africa/LibrevilleAfrica/Libreville
(GMT+1:00) Africa/LuandaAfrica/Luanda
(GMT+1:00) Africa/MalaboAfrica/Malabo
(GMT+1:00) Africa/NdjamenaAfrica/Ndjamena
(GMT+1:00) Africa/NiameyAfrica/Niamey
(GMT+1:00) Africa/Porto-NovoAfrica/Porto-Novo
(GMT+1:00) Africa/TunisAfrica/Tunis
(GMT+1:00) Africa/WindhoekAfrica/Windhoek
(GMT+1:00) Arctic/LongyearbyenArctic/Longyearbyen
(GMT+1:00) Atlantic/Jan_MayenAtlantic/Jan_Mayen
(GMT+1:00) CETCET
(GMT+1:00) Etc/GMT-1Etc/GMT-1
(GMT+1:00) Europe/AmsterdamEurope/Amsterdam
(GMT+1:00) Europe/AndorraEurope/Andorra
(GMT+1:00) Europe/BelgradeEurope/Belgrade
(GMT+1:00) Europe/BerlinEurope/Berlin
(GMT+1:00) Europe/BratislavaEurope/Bratislava
(GMT+1:00) Europe/BrusselsEurope/Brussels
(GMT+1:00) Europe/BudapestEurope/Budapest
(GMT+1:00) Europe/BusingenEurope/Busingen
(GMT+1:00) Europe/CopenhagenEurope/Copenhagen
(GMT+1:00) Europe/GibraltarEurope/Gibraltar
(GMT+1:00) Europe/LjubljanaEurope/Ljubljana
(GMT+1:00) Europe/LuxembourgEurope/Luxembourg
(GMT+1:00) Europe/MadridEurope/Madrid
(GMT+1:00) Europe/MaltaEurope/Malta
(GMT+1:00) Europe/MonacoEurope/Monaco
(GMT+1:00) Europe/OsloEurope/Oslo
(GMT+1:00) Europe/ParisEurope/Paris
(GMT+1:00) Europe/PodgoricaEurope/Podgorica
(GMT+1:00) Europe/PragueEurope/Prague
(GMT+1:00) Europe/RomeEurope/Rome
(GMT+1:00) Europe/San_MarinoEurope/San_Marino
(GMT+1:00) Europe/SarajevoEurope/Sarajevo
(GMT+1:00) Europe/SkopjeEurope/Skopje
(GMT+1:00) Europe/StockholmEurope/Stockholm
(GMT+1:00) Europe/TiraneEurope/Tirane
(GMT+1:00) Europe/VaduzEurope/Vaduz
(GMT+1:00) Europe/VaticanEurope/Vatican
(GMT+1:00) Europe/ViennaEurope/Vienna
(GMT+1:00) Europe/WarsawEurope/Warsaw
(GMT+1:00) Europe/ZagrebEurope/Zagreb
(GMT+1:00) Europe/ZurichEurope/Zurich
(GMT+1:00) METMET
(GMT+1:00) PolandPoland
(GMT+1:00) ECTECT
(GMT+2:00) Africa/BlantyreAfrica/Blantyre
(GMT+2:00) Africa/BujumburaAfrica/Bujumbura
(GMT+2:00) Africa/CairoAfrica/Cairo
(GMT+2:00) Africa/GaboroneAfrica/Gaborone
(GMT+2:00) Africa/HarareAfrica/Harare
(GMT+2:00) Africa/JohannesburgAfrica/Johannesburg
(GMT+2:00) Africa/KigaliAfrica/Kigali
(GMT+2:00) Africa/LubumbashiAfrica/Lubumbashi
(GMT+2:00) Africa/LusakaAfrica/Lusaka
(GMT+2:00) Africa/MaputoAfrica/Maputo
(GMT+2:00) Africa/MaseruAfrica/Maseru
(GMT+2:00) Africa/MbabaneAfrica/Mbabane
(GMT+2:00) Africa/TripoliAfrica/Tripoli
(GMT+2:00) Asia/AmmanAsia/Amman
(GMT+2:00) Asia/BeirutAsia/Beirut
(GMT+2:00) Asia/DamascusAsia/Damascus
(GMT+2:00) Asia/GazaAsia/Gaza
(GMT+2:00) Asia/HebronAsia/Hebron
(GMT+2:00) Asia/IstanbulAsia/Istanbul
(GMT+2:00) Asia/JerusalemAsia/Jerusalem
(GMT+2:00) Asia/NicosiaAsia/Nicosia
(GMT+2:00) Asia/Tel_AvivAsia/Tel_Aviv
(GMT+2:00) EETEET
(GMT+2:00) EgyptEgypt
(GMT+2:00) Etc/GMT-2Etc/GMT-2
(GMT+2:00) Europe/AthensEurope/Athens
(GMT+2:00) Europe/BucharestEurope/Bucharest
(GMT+2:00) Europe/ChisinauEurope/Chisinau
(GMT+2:00) Europe/HelsinkiEurope/Helsinki
(GMT+2:00) Europe/IstanbulEurope/Istanbul
(GMT+2:00) Europe/KievEurope/Kiev
(GMT+2:00) Europe/MariehamnEurope/Mariehamn
(GMT+2:00) Europe/NicosiaEurope/Nicosia
(GMT+2:00) Europe/RigaEurope/Riga
(GMT+2:00) Europe/SimferopolEurope/Simferopol
(GMT+2:00) Europe/SofiaEurope/Sofia
(GMT+2:00) Europe/TallinnEurope/Tallinn
(GMT+2:00) Europe/TiraspolEurope/Tiraspol
(GMT+2:00) Europe/UzhgorodEurope/Uzhgorod
(GMT+2:00) Europe/VilniusEurope/Vilnius
(GMT+2:00) Europe/ZaporozhyeEurope/Zaporozhye
(GMT+2:00) IsraelIsrael
(GMT+2:00) LibyaLibya
(GMT+2:00) TurkeyTurkey
(GMT+2:00) ARTART
(GMT+2:00) CATCAT
(GMT+3:00) Africa/Addis_AbabaAfrica/Addis_Ababa
(GMT+3:00) Africa/AsmaraAfrica/Asmara
(GMT+3:00) Africa/AsmeraAfrica/Asmera
(GMT+3:00) Africa/Dar_es_SalaamAfrica/Dar_es_Salaam
(GMT+3:00) Africa/DjiboutiAfrica/Djibouti
(GMT+3:00) Africa/JubaAfrica/Juba
(GMT+3:00) Africa/KampalaAfrica/Kampala
(GMT+3:00) Africa/KhartoumAfrica/Khartoum
(GMT+3:00) Africa/MogadishuAfrica/Mogadishu
(GMT+3:00) Africa/NairobiAfrica/Nairobi
(GMT+3:00) Antarctica/SyowaAntarctica/Syowa
(GMT+3:00) Asia/AdenAsia/Aden
(GMT+3:00) Asia/BaghdadAsia/Baghdad
(GMT+3:00) Asia/BahrainAsia/Bahrain
(GMT+3:00) Asia/KuwaitAsia/Kuwait
(GMT+3:00) Asia/QatarAsia/Qatar
(GMT+3:00) Asia/RiyadhAsia/Riyadh
(GMT+3:00) Etc/GMT-3Etc/GMT-3
(GMT+3:00) Europe/KaliningradEurope/Kaliningrad
(GMT+3:00) Europe/MinskEurope/Minsk
(GMT+3:00) Indian/AntananarivoIndian/Antananarivo
(GMT+3:00) Indian/ComoroIndian/Comoro
(GMT+3:00) Indian/MayotteIndian/Mayotte
(GMT+3:00) EATEAT
(GMT+3:30) Asia/TehranAsia/Tehran
(GMT+3:30) IranIran
(GMT+4:00) Asia/BakuAsia/Baku
(GMT+4:00) Asia/DubaiAsia/Dubai
(GMT+4:00) Asia/MuscatAsia/Muscat
(GMT+4:00) Asia/TbilisiAsia/Tbilisi
(GMT+4:00) Asia/YerevanAsia/Yerevan
(GMT+4:00) Etc/GMT-4Etc/GMT-4
(GMT+4:00) Europe/MoscowEurope/Moscow
(GMT+4:00) Europe/SamaraEurope/Samara
(GMT+4:00) Europe/VolgogradEurope/Volgograd
(GMT+4:00) Indian/MaheIndian/Mahe
(GMT+4:00) Indian/MauritiusIndian/Mauritius
(GMT+4:00) Indian/ReunionIndian/Reunion
(GMT+4:00) W-SUW-SU
(GMT+4:00) NETNET
(GMT+4:30) Asia/KabulAsia/Kabul
(GMT+5:00) Antarctica/MawsonAntarctica/Mawson
(GMT+5:00) Asia/AqtauAsia/Aqtau
(GMT+5:00) Asia/AqtobeAsia/Aqtobe
(GMT+5:00) Asia/AshgabatAsia/Ashgabat
(GMT+5:00) Asia/AshkhabadAsia/Ashkhabad
(GMT+5:00) Asia/DushanbeAsia/Dushanbe
(GMT+5:00) Asia/KarachiAsia/Karachi
(GMT+5:00) Asia/OralAsia/Oral
(GMT+5:00) Asia/SamarkandAsia/Samarkand
(GMT+5:00) Asia/TashkentAsia/Tashkent
(GMT+5:00) Etc/GMT-5Etc/GMT-5
(GMT+5:00) Indian/KerguelenIndian/Kerguelen
(GMT+5:00) Indian/MaldivesIndian/Maldives
(GMT+5:00) PLTPLT
(GMT+5:30) Asia/CalcuttaAsia/Calcutta
(GMT+5:30) Asia/ColomboAsia/Colombo
(GMT+5:30) Asia/KolkataAsia/Kolkata
(GMT+5:30) ISTIST
(GMT+5:45) Asia/KathmanduAsia/Kathmandu
(GMT+5:45) Asia/KatmanduAsia/Katmandu
(GMT+6:00) Antarctica/VostokAntarctica/Vostok
(GMT+6:00) Asia/AlmatyAsia/Almaty
(GMT+6:00) Asia/BishkekAsia/Bishkek
(GMT+6:00) Asia/DaccaAsia/Dacca
(GMT+6:00) Asia/DhakaAsia/Dhaka
(GMT+6:00) Asia/QyzylordaAsia/Qyzylorda
(GMT+6:00) Asia/ThimbuAsia/Thimbu
(GMT+6:00) Asia/ThimphuAsia/Thimphu
(GMT+6:00) Asia/YekaterinburgAsia/Yekaterinburg
(GMT+6:00) Etc/GMT-6Etc/GMT-6
(GMT+6:00) Indian/ChagosIndian/Chagos
(GMT+6:00) BSTBST
(GMT+6:30) Asia/RangoonAsia/Rangoon
(GMT+6:30) Indian/CocosIndian/Cocos
(GMT+7:00) Antarctica/DavisAntarctica/Davis
(GMT+7:00) Asia/BangkokAsia/Bangkok
(GMT+7:00) Asia/Ho_Chi_MinhAsia/Ho_Chi_Minh
(GMT+7:00) Asia/HovdAsia/Hovd
(GMT+7:00) Asia/JakartaAsia/Jakarta
(GMT+7:00) Asia/NovokuznetskAsia/Novokuznetsk
(GMT+7:00) Asia/NovosibirskAsia/Novosibirsk
(GMT+7:00) Asia/OmskAsia/Omsk
(GMT+7:00) Asia/Phnom_PenhAsia/Phnom_Penh
(GMT+7:00) Asia/PontianakAsia/Pontianak
(GMT+7:00) Asia/SaigonAsia/Saigon
(GMT+7:00) Asia/VientianeAsia/Vientiane
(GMT+7:00) Etc/GMT-7Etc/GMT-7
(GMT+7:00) Indian/ChristmasIndian/Christmas
(GMT+7:00) VSTVST
(GMT+8:00) Antarctica/CaseyAntarctica/Casey
(GMT+8:00) Asia/BruneiAsia/Brunei
(GMT+8:00) Asia/ChoibalsanAsia/Choibalsan
(GMT+8:00) Asia/ChongqingAsia/Chongqing
(GMT+8:00) Asia/ChungkingAsia/Chungking
(GMT+8:00) Asia/HarbinAsia/Harbin
(GMT+8:00) Asia/Hong_KongAsia/Hong_Kong
(GMT+8:00) Asia/KashgarAsia/Kashgar
(GMT+8:00) Asia/KrasnoyarskAsia/Krasnoyarsk
(GMT+8:00) Asia/Kuala_LumpurAsia/Kuala_Lumpur
(GMT+8:00) Asia/KuchingAsia/Kuching
(GMT+8:00) Asia/MacaoAsia/Macao
(GMT+8:00) Asia/MacauAsia/Macau
(GMT+8:00) Asia/MakassarAsia/Makassar
(GMT+8:00) Asia/ManilaAsia/Manila
(GMT+8:00) Asia/ShanghaiAsia/Shanghai
(GMT+8:00) Asia/SingaporeAsia/Singapore
(GMT+8:00) Asia/TaipeiAsia/Taipei
(GMT+8:00) Asia/Ujung_PandangAsia/Ujung_Pandang
(GMT+8:00) Asia/UlaanbaatarAsia/Ulaanbaatar
(GMT+8:00) Asia/Ulan_BatorAsia/Ulan_Bator
(GMT+8:00) Asia/UrumqiAsia/Urumqi
(GMT+8:00) Australia/PerthAustralia/Perth
(GMT+8:00) Australia/WestAustralia/West
(GMT+8:00) Etc/GMT-8Etc/GMT-8
(GMT+8:00) HongkongHongkong
(GMT+8:00) PRCPRC
(GMT+8:00) SingaporeSingapore
(GMT+8:00) CTTCTT
(GMT+8:45) Australia/EuclaAustralia/Eucla
(GMT+9:00) Asia/DiliAsia/Dili
(GMT+9:00) Asia/IrkutskAsia/Irkutsk
(GMT+9:00) Asia/JayapuraAsia/Jayapura
(GMT+9:00) Asia/PyongyangAsia/Pyongyang
(GMT+9:00) Asia/SeoulAsia/Seoul
(GMT+9:00) Asia/TokyoAsia/Tokyo
(GMT+9:00) Etc/GMT-9Etc/GMT-9
(GMT+9:00) JapanJapan
(GMT+9:00) Pacific/PalauPacific/Palau
(GMT+9:00) ROKROK
(GMT+9:00) JSTJST
(GMT+9:30) Australia/AdelaideAustralia/Adelaide
(GMT+9:30) Australia/Broken_HillAustralia/Broken_Hill
(GMT+9:30) Australia/DarwinAustralia/Darwin
(GMT+9:30) Australia/NorthAustralia/North
(GMT+9:30) Australia/SouthAustralia/South
(GMT+9:30) Australia/YancowinnaAustralia/Yancowinna
(GMT+9:30) ACTACT
(GMT+10:00) Antarctica/DumontDUrvilleAntarctica/DumontDUrville
(GMT+10:00) Asia/KhandygaAsia/Khandyga
(GMT+10:00) Asia/YakutskAsia/Yakutsk
(GMT+10:00) Australia/ACTAustralia/ACT
(GMT+10:00) Australia/BrisbaneAustralia/Brisbane
(GMT+10:00) Australia/CanberraAustralia/Canberra
(GMT+10:00) Australia/CurrieAustralia/Currie
(GMT+10:00) Australia/HobartAustralia/Hobart
(GMT+10:00) Australia/LindemanAustralia/Lindeman
(GMT+10:00) Australia/MelbourneAustralia/Melbourne
(GMT+10:00) Australia/NSWAustralia/NSW
(GMT+10:00) Australia/QueenslandAustralia/Queensland
(GMT+10:00) Australia/SydneyAustralia/Sydney
(GMT+10:00) Australia/TasmaniaAustralia/Tasmania
(GMT+10:00) Australia/VictoriaAustralia/Victoria
(GMT+10:00) Etc/GMT-10Etc/GMT-10
(GMT+10:00) Pacific/ChuukPacific/Chuuk
(GMT+10:00) Pacific/GuamPacific/Guam
(GMT+10:00) Pacific/Port_MoresbyPacific/Port_Moresby
(GMT+10:00) Pacific/SaipanPacific/Saipan
(GMT+10:00) Pacific/TrukPacific/Truk
(GMT+10:00) Pacific/YapPacific/Yap
(GMT+10:00) AETAET
(GMT+10:30) Australia/LHIAustralia/LHI
(GMT+10:30) Australia/Lord_HoweAustralia/Lord_Howe
(GMT+11:00) Antarctica/MacquarieAntarctica/Macquarie
(GMT+11:00) Asia/SakhalinAsia/Sakhalin
(GMT+11:00) Asia/Ust-NeraAsia/Ust-Nera
(GMT+11:00) Asia/VladivostokAsia/Vladivostok
(GMT+11:00) Etc/GMT-11Etc/GMT-11
(GMT+11:00) Pacific/EfatePacific/Efate
(GMT+11:00) Pacific/GuadalcanalPacific/Guadalcanal
(GMT+11:00) Pacific/KosraePacific/Kosrae
(GMT+11:00) Pacific/NoumeaPacific/Noumea
(GMT+11:00) Pacific/PohnpeiPacific/Pohnpei
(GMT+11:00) Pacific/PonapePacific/Ponape
(GMT+11:00) SSTSST
(GMT+11:30) Pacific/NorfolkPacific/Norfolk
(GMT+12:00) Antarctica/McMurdoAntarctica/McMurdo
(GMT+12:00) Antarctica/South_PoleAntarctica/South_Pole
(GMT+12:00) Asia/AnadyrAsia/Anadyr
(GMT+12:00) Asia/KamchatkaAsia/Kamchatka
(GMT+12:00) Asia/MagadanAsia/Magadan
(GMT+12:00) Etc/GMT-12Etc/GMT-12
(GMT+12:00) KwajaleinKwajalein
(GMT+12:00) NZNZ
(GMT+12:00) Pacific/AucklandPacific/Auckland
(GMT+12:00) Pacific/FijiPacific/Fiji
(GMT+12:00) Pacific/FunafutiPacific/Funafuti
(GMT+12:00) Pacific/KwajaleinPacific/Kwajalein
(GMT+12:00) Pacific/MajuroPacific/Majuro
(GMT+12:00) Pacific/NauruPacific/Nauru
(GMT+12:00) Pacific/TarawaPacific/Tarawa
(GMT+12:00) Pacific/WakePacific/Wake
(GMT+12:00) Pacific/WallisPacific/Wallis
(GMT+12:00) NSTNST
(GMT+12:45) NZ-CHATNZ-CHAT
(GMT+12:45) Pacific/ChathamPacific/Chatham
(GMT+13:00) Etc/GMT-13Etc/GMT-13
(GMT+13:00) Pacific/ApiaPacific/Apia
(GMT+13:00) Pacific/EnderburyPacific/Enderbury
(GMT+13:00) Pacific/FakaofoPacific/Fakaofo
(GMT+13:00) Pacific/TongatapuPacific/Tongatapu
(GMT+13:00) MITMIT
(GMT+14:00) Etc/GMT-14Etc/GMT-14
(GMT+14:00) Pacific/KiritimatiPacific/Kiritimati
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to perform it:

```
private ArrayList<String> allTimeZone=new ArrayList<String>;

String[] options = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();

        for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            allTimeZone.add(options[i]);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, allTimeZone);
        sp_select_timezone.setAdapter(adapter);


 sp_select_timezone.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                // your code here
                for (int i = 0; i < allTimeZone.size(); i++) {
                    if (allTimeZone.get(i).contains((CharSequence) parentView.getItemAtPosition(position))) {
                        // City_id = allCitiesItems.get(i).getCityId();
                        Log.e("TimeZone", " " + allTimeZone.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // your code here
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on MadProgrammer's answer, if someone wants in functional style:

```
List<String> getTimeZones() {
            return ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()
                    .stream()
                    .map(TimeZone::getTimeZone)
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(TimeZone::getRawOffset))
                    .map(timeZone -> getTimeZone(timeZone) + timeZone.getID())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
```